# How to use loops to parse contents from multiple URLs in JSON - Selenium in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops, selenium-webdriver, append

I am trying to parse data in our organization's HR system for people's profiles. I am using Selenium in Python to do the work but I encounter some difficulties.

I have the URLs list and I want to extract people who report to them. The dummy data displayed as below (same strcuture for all URLs):

```
[{'Name': 'Jon Doe','prop': {'ID': '5646'},'ManagerName': 'Kat'},
{'Name': 'Maokai','prop': {'ID': '48521'},'ManagerName': 'Malphite'},
{'Name': 'Ryze','prop': {'ID': '43547'},'ManagerName': 'Wukong'},
{'Name': 'Zed','prop': {'ID': '98244'},'ManagerName': 'Annie'}]
```

I tried the coding below but can only extract info for the 10th URL...The output lists don't aggregate. Can anyone tell me anything wrong with the code and how to fix it?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'xxx\chromedriver.exe')

for url in URL_lst[:10]:
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

data = json.loads(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)

NAME_lst = []
ID_lst = []
Manager_lst = []

for profile in data:
    NAME_lst.append(profile['Name'])
    ID_lst.append(profile['prop']['ID'])
    Manager_lst.append(profile['ManagerName'])

df_outputs = pd.DataFrame({'NAME':NAME_lst,
                           'ID':ID_lst,
                            'Manager':Manager_lst})
```

The expected outputs would be the aggregation for the 10 URLs' outputs.

For security reasons, I cannot post the URLs. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? Note that there is an unclosed quotes at ID_lst.append(profile['prop']['ID'])

Comment: also looks like there is an indentation after the first FOR loop. Therefore you are only seeing the last output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found the solution myself:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'xxx\chromedriver.exe')
output=[]
for url in URL_lst[:10]:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    data = json.loads(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
    output.append(data)
```

Then, create loops to append info.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like indentation issue. Check this once
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'xxx\chromedriver.exe')

```
for url in URL_lst[:10]:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)

    data = json.loads(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)

    NAME_lst = []
    ID_lst = []
    Manager_lst = []

    for profile in data:
        NAME_lst.append(profile['Name'])
        ID_lst.append(profile['prop']['ID'])
        Manager_lst.append(profile['ManagerName'])
```